# Git: How to check if new files have been added to the remote repository, but not in local

Tags: git

The situation is the following:
I created a remote repository so I can work with it from two different places with different machines.

Every time I work from a location generally I don't modify the old files, but I just add new files to the repository (I'm studying Java, so I'm adding all the exercises that I do in that repository).

I know that with `git pull` I get the newer version of the remote repository, but if I use `git diff` it says that there are no differences, even if in the remote repository I added new files from the other location.

Before pulling I would check if new files have been pushed to the remote repository. Is there a command that shows not only the differences on existing files, but also the new files pushed to the remote repository?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do use the `git diff`? Can you let me see the command line?

Comment: Do you want to just want to list the files that were added?

Comment: I think you should try to use `git fetch` command, and learn its difference with `git pull`.

Comment: Yes, Jubobs, thanks.
But my mark is still not publicly displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command lists the files that were added between `<revA>` and `<revB>`:

```
git diff --diff-filter=A --name-only <revA> <revB>
```

In your case, `<revA>` would be master, and `<revB>` would be `origin/master` (under the assumption that your remote is indeed called "origin").

As jthill points out in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32540440/git-how-to-check-if-new-files-have-been-added-to-the-remote-repository-but-not/32540714?noredirect=1#comment52938761_32540714), don't forget to run

```
git fetch
```

beforehand, to make sure your local repo knows all about the latest changes in the remote.

Comment: that should do it. fetch might be worth mentioning.